# Is it possible to know how many times a user connected to Oracle Database?

Tags: database

Is it possible to know how many times a user connected to Oracle Database?
If possible where we can find this information?

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: You're probably better asking this on [dba.se]

Comment: Thank you Mike.It looks more appropriate to ask the question in 'Database Administrators'.I will post thae question there.